# Query Performance Netezza SQL

Tags: sql, performance, for-loop, stored-procedures, netezza

What is the best way to have the below logic to be in a single Netezza SQL. I implemented the logic in a for loop but for my data set it is taking a long time in netezza (say 47 mins to complete the loop) I have two tables, “TABLE - A”  (Sector_ID | Value) and “TABLE B” holds which sector_id is intersected with other sector_id combination.

Now, the TABLE-A will be sorted descending on Value, and need to take the each highest sector_id from table A and eliminate all the corresponding intersected sector_id for point A in TABLE- B.

For Example,

```
TABLE – A (After Sorting)
SECTOR_ID   VALUE(DESC)         DELETED ROWS
    6   150
    1   140         DELETED
    4   50
    2   45          DELETED
    3   15

TABLE – B 
SECTOR_ID   INTERSECTED_ID  DELETED ROWS
    6       6
    6       1       DELETED
    6       2       DELETED
    1       1       DELETED
    1       4       DELETED
    1       2       DELETED
    4       4
    4       1       DELETED
    2       6       DELETED
    2       1       DELETED
    2       2       DELETED
    3       3
```

Now the remaining values in TABLE – A will be the desired output. Please suggest. The DB I am using is Netezza.

Comment: Can you post your loop code? Even if it's just pseudo-code, that would help inform what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: SQL8:='create table temp_IDS as select row_number() over(order by s_value desc) as rn, c_siteid, 0 as selected from sect order by s_value desc';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL8;
select count(*) into table_Count from temp_IDS; 
for i in 1..(table_Count) loop
select selected into selValue from temp_IDS where rn = i;   
 if(selValue = 0) then
select c_siteid into buffer_siteid from temp_IDS where rn =i;
      
  SQL8:='delete from sect where c_siteid in
  (select site_id from dcpT where c_siteid = ' || buffer_siteid || 'and c_siteid <> site_id)';

Comment: SQL8:='update temp_IDS set selected = 3 where c_siteid in
  (select site_id from dcpT where c_siteid = ' || buffer_siteid || 'and c_siteid <> site_id)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL8;
 end if;
end loop;

Comment: Previous two comments together is my complete for loop. Sorry didnt find a link to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt to restate your problem, so if it is not accurate let me know in the comments so that we can formulate it (and this answer).

You need to remove records in `table_a` when `table_a.sector_id` appears in the list of previous `table_b.intersected_id`s given that `table_b` is sorted by `table_a.value`.

## Solution

Note that this solution is not relegated to Netezza-only, but rather relational algebra. Also, as far as I know, this will be faster than any cursor or loop-based approach for any RDBMS.

The biggest chore is setting up the list of `sector_id`s that need to be deleted from `table_a`. See in-line comments for descriptions.

```
create temporary table table_b_extended as
  with tba as ( --Enhance table_a to include a row number.
    select
      row_number() over (order by sector_value desc) rwn
      ,*
    from
      table_a
  ), tab as ( --Join tables A and B together to attach the sorting key.
    select
      tba.rwn table_a_rwn
      ,row_number() over (order by tba.rwn) table_b_rwn
      ,tbb.*
      ,case
        when tbb.sector_id = tbb.intersected_id
          then 1
        else 0
      end sector_is_intersected
    from
      tba
      join table_b tbb on
        tba.sector_id = tbb.sector_id
  )
  select * from tab
distribute on (sector_id);

-- Find out the row where the intersected id first appears.
create temporary table table_b_first_appearance as
  select
    intersected_id sector_id
    ,min(table_b_rwn) first_appearance
  from
    table_b_extended
  where
    sector_id <> intersected_id
  group by 1
distribute on random;

create temporary table table_a_deletes as
  with pid as ( --Get all previous intersected_ids.
    select distinct
      tab.*
      ,case --See if this row is after the intersected_id's first appearance.
        when app.first_appearance < tab.table_b_rwn then 1
        else 0
      end sector_in_previous
    from
      table_b_extended tab
      left outer join table_b_first_appearance app using (sector_id)
  ), vld as ( --Select records that qualify to delete from table_a.
    select distinct
      intersected_id
    from
      pid
    where
      --If it hasn't been seen and isn't equal to the intersected_id, delete it.
      sector_is_intersected + sector_in_previous = 0
  )
  select 
    * 
  from 
    vld
distribute on random;
```

Given your initial input for `table_b`:

```
+------------+----------------+
| sector_id  | intersected_id |
+------------+----------------+
|          6 |              6 |
|          1 |              2 |
|          1 |              1 |
|          1 |              4 |
|          4 |              4 |
|          4 |              1 |
|          2 |              6 |
|          2 |              1 |
|          2 |              2 |
|          3 |              3 |
|          6 |              1 |
|          6 |              2 |
+------------+----------------+
```

This generates a table, `table_a_deletes`, with two values: `1` and `2`. Then deleting from `table_a` is simple.

```
delete from table_a tbl
  where tbl.sector_id in (select sector_id from table_a_deletes);
```

And I'm not sure if those `DELETED` flags in `table_b` need to be replicated or not, but if so:

```
delete from table_b tbl
  where
    tbl.sector_id in (select sector_id from table_a_deletes)
    or tbl.sector_id <> tbl.intersected_id;
```

### Performance

On an 8 SPU test system, including the delete steps:

#### Test 1

- `table_a` size 14976
- `table_b` size 179427095
- Runtime 2:50

#### Test 2

- `table_a` size 14976
- `table_b` size 196240063
- Runtime 3:16

#### Test 3

- `table_a` size 19919
- `table_b` size 317428924
- Runtime 5:28

By far the longest time is creating the `_extended` table. So if you can use some other comparator rather than establishing a new `id` field, that would be best.

### Extra Cases

Here are some different cases to show that it works in a variety of situations. In all cases, I have just modified `table_b`, since changing `table_a` is always the trivial case.

#### Case 1

`table_b`

```
+--+-------------+------------------+--+
|  |  sector_id  |  intersected_id  |  |
+--+-------------+------------------+--+
|  |          6  |               6  |  |
|  |          1  |               1  |  |
|  |          1  |               2  |  |
|  |          4  |               4  |  |
|  |          4  |               1  |  |
|  |          2  |               6  |  |
|  |          2  |               1  |  |
|  |          2  |               2  |  |
|  |          3  |               3  |  |
+--+-------------+------------------+--+
```

Deletes `1` and `2`.

#### Case 2

`table_b`

```
+--+-------------+------------------+--+
|  |  sector_id  |  intersected_id  |  |
+--+-------------+------------------+--+
|  |          6  |               6  |  |
|  |          6  |               1  |  |
|  |          1  |               1  |  |
|  |          1  |               2  |  |
|  |          4  |               4  |  |
|  |          4  |               1  |  |
|  |          2  |               6  |  |
|  |          2  |               1  |  |
|  |          2  |               2  |  |
|  |          3  |               3  |  |
+--+-------------+------------------+--+
```

Deletes `1`.

#### Case 3

`table_b`

```
+--+-------------+------------------+--+
|  |  sector_id  |  intersected_id  |  |
+--+-------------+------------------+--+
|  |          6  |               6  |  |
|  |          1  |               1  |  |
|  |          1  |               4  |  |
|  |          4  |               4  |  |
|  |          4  |               1  |  |
|  |          2  |               6  |  |
|  |          2  |               1  |  |
|  |          2  |               2  |  |
|  |          3  |               3  |  |
+--+-------------+------------------+--+
```

Deletes `1`, `4`, and `6`.

Comment: Hi Jeremytwfortune, thanks for the query provided. But this is some how executing very slow than the loop i implemented. The piece of code which is causing more time is mentioned below in this comment. Is there a way to tweak it to improve performance.

Comment: pid as ( --Get all previous intersected_ids.
    select distinct
      tab.*
      ,max(
        case 
          when tab.sector_id = prv.intersected_id 
            then 1 
          else 0 
        end) over (
          partition by tab.rwn
      ) sector_in_previous
    from
      tab
      left outer join tab prv on
        tab.rwn > prv.rwn --Previous records.
        and prv.sector_id <> prv.intersected_id --These never delete records.
  )

Comment: That SQL itself is taking a long time and giving time out exceptions. Increasing query time can let this sql to run, however given the size of my dataset i feel that this SQL still needs a tune than use it as is. I havent finished the testing of the complete SQL given by you cause of this to give a better comment on the output. Please suggest.

Comment: I've updated the solution to remove the large join. Try this version out.